# java.lang.Exception: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY012 stack shape inconsistent;

Tags: java, websphere, verifyerror

We have just migrated from IBM Websphere 7 (Java 1.6) to Websphere 9 (Java 1.8).
I'm facing issue with Long casting, code breaks while loading jsp, code snippet below (This code is written in JSP):

```
        long caseNum = 0L, empid = 0L;
        Long employeeId;


            employeeId = ((Long) request.getAttribute("EMPID") == null) ? 0L
                    : (Long) request.getAttribute("EMPID");
            empid = employeeId.longValue();
```

Below is the stack strace,

**java.lang.Exception: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY012 stack shape inconsistent; class=com/ibm/_jsp/_TMTSSTaskSummary, method=_jspService(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V, pc=13805**
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/ibm/_jsp/_TMTSSTaskSummary._jspService(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V @13805: JBifnull
  Reason:
    Type top (current frame, locals[120]) is not assignable to 'java/lang/Long' (stack map, locals[120])
  Current Frame:
    bci: @13805
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/ibm/_jsp/_TMTSSTaskSummary', 'javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest', 'javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse', 'javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext', 'javax/servlet/http/HttpSession', 'javax/servlet/ServletContext', 'javax/servlet/ServletConfig', 'javax/servlet/jsp/JspWriter', 'java/lang/Object', 'javax/servlet/jsp/JspWriter', 'com/presentation/view/pageelements/SecurityAttr', 'java/lang/String', integer, 'java/lang/String', 'javax/servlet/http/HttpSession', 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/String', integer, integer, 'java/util/Map', integer, 'java/lang/String', integer, 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/String', integer, integer, integer, integer, 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/Object', 'java/lang/Object', 'java/lang/Object', 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/Object', 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/Object', 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang','2017-08-04 15:26:47.067','0','A','TMTSS~100: UnKnown Error','859469','518722','null','null')

Can anybody suggest any solution for this.
I read about using splitverify but it works with AspectJ. Is there any other solution?

Comment: did you resolve this please ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that

1. You are trying to typecast a null object which is raising an error or

   ```
   long caseNum = 0L, empid = 0L;
   Long employeeId;


       employeeId = (request.getAttribute("EMPID") == null) ? 0L
               : (Long) request.getAttribute("EMPID");
       empid = employeeId.longValue();
   ```
2. You are trying to cast a string or any other object to Long. In case, it is string, use Long.parseLong()

   ```
       employeeId = (request.getAttribute("EMPID") == null) ? 0L
               : Long.parseLong(request.getAttribute("EMPID"));
       empid = employeeId.longValue();
   ```

Also, a general advice that you don't really need to use Long employeeId to convert to long as [auto-unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) should handle that.

Comment: I'm using ternary operator so there wont be typecasting null object issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be java 7 compatibility issue.. 
In Jdk 7 you can use -XX:-UseSplitVerifier.
And if you are using JDK 8 -XX:-UseSplitVerifier is deprecated and replaced with -noverify.
 I have added -noverify to jvm argument and it resolved my issue.